# yarn add brain.js not working - no errors but doesnt actually import?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarn-v2, brain.js

I was trying to install brain.js into my javascript program with `npm install brain.js`, but this returned an error (it also did this on repl.it, so I don't think its a problem with my computer), so I tried to use yarn. I did `yarn add brain.js` , which seemed to work, but when I tried to run the examples on GitHub the program said brain was not defined in `const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork(config);`, which means the library was not imported.

Does anyone know why this isn't working? Keep in mind I am not experienced with javascript and just wanted to try brain.js for myself. I installed yarn with `npm install yarn`, so I assume this installs the latest version so I put v2 in the tags. Please correct me if I am wrong so I can change it.

Comment: You have to actually import the module after installing it

Comment: thanks, how can I do this? sorry, ive never imported this way before.

Comment: is it `yarn import brain.js`?

Comment: You can try `import * as brain from 'brain.js'` in your javascript file

Comment: I'll try in a repl. I am not at my home right now so I will try there later.

Comment: It gave me this error - `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I have to make a module?

Comment: It's also giving me an error because it's trying to update npm which, currently, is really problematic for me. I'll try when I get to my computer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: also didnt work on my pc.

Comment: You didn't specify if your code should run in the browser or in node

Comment: I tried both. It didnt work.